# Xamarin.Android How to separate speech to text sentences into separate words

Tags: android, xamarin, speech

I have Android speech recognition set up in my Xamarin.Android. Currently the user can say a word which is then shown in a textview.

What I want to do is split a sentence into separate words using a separator word such as 'and'.

For example: if I say 'fish and chips' in one sentence, the words *fish* and *chips* should be split into separate strings and added to a list view.

Is this possible?

Comment: Does my answer work for you?

Comment: Works great thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can separate strings by using [String.Split](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/how-to/parse-strings-using-split):

For example:

```
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    string testStr = "fish and chips in one sentence";

    string[] separatedStrs = testStr.Split(new[] { "and" }, StringSplitOptions.None);

    foreach (var item in separatedStrs)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item);
    }
}
```